# Cannot copy long path files in Windows 10 within Dockerfile COPY

Tags: windows, maven, docker, dockerfile

I build an image from a base image. In the Dockerfile of the base image I run a command `ONBUILD COPY . /workspace`. When I build my image from this base image then it copy all the files from current directory to the /workspace directory of the result image.
Then I run `mvn clean install` from the Dockerfile with an error: `cannot find symbol`. The problem is that all the `.java` files that has long path names are not copied from current directory to the `/workspace` directory and so the error.

I tried to activate long pathns in `Local Computer Policy`, I also checked it in the registry, but it does't helped. I tried to run CMD as Administrator and then also tried to build from Git Bash command line, none fixed the problem.
Does anyone knows what could be the problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: Same problem here. Maybe the 260 character problem from this issue that had already been solved... mmh... https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15775

Comment: I cannot test it now, I don't have this project anymore but I remember that we found a workaround at that time.

Comment: I found out, that this problem only happens, when using buildkit as builder. I reported an issue: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1366 When using the old docker build (without "export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1") everything works fine